# Making selections linked to definitions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So how this was thought to work was: Start script, make a selectable menu so the user can select what to do (add, divide, multiply and so forth). But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Something like this:

Press 1 for add
Press 2 for multiply

and so forth. I have just made the `add` definition as of now, but I plan on using the same template when doing multiply and divide etc.

```
# Calculations
def add(a, b):
    print "Write the numbers to add"
    adda = int(raw_input("First number: "))
    addb = int(raw_input("Second number: "))
    print "Adding %d and %d together" % (a, b)
    print "%d + %d="
    return a + b

# Choose what to do
print "Write what you want do do: add, subtract, multiply or divide"
```

EDITED TO:

```
# Calculations
def math(command):
    print "Write the numbers to %s" % command
    a = int(raw_input("First number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Second number: "))
    if command == 'add':
        return a + b
    elif command == 'subtract':
        return a - b
    elif command == 'multiply':
        return a * b
    elif command == 'divide':
        return a / b
    else:
        return 'not a valid command'

# Choose what to do
print "Write what you want to do.. add, subtract, multiply or divide"
command = raw_input("Do you want to add, multiply, divide or subtract: ")
```

Problem here is that it won't print out the value for return a + b for example, I don't have any link to the def math(), so I don't think it will run.. any way to solve this?

Comment: You should use `raw_input` to find out what the user wants to do, similar to how you get the numbers

Comment: Note that your add, subtract, divide and multiply routines will each need to collect two numbers, so you should consider writing a function to collect the inputs. This should avoid a lot of unnecessary duplication of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `raw_input` to find out what the user wants to do, similar to how you get the numbers in the `add()` function.

```
# Choose what to do
choice = raw_input("Write what you want do do: add, subtract, multiply or divide")
if choice == 'add':
    add()
```

However because in `add()` you ask for the numbers the user wants to add, you do not want to call `add()` with parameters, so change

```
def add(a, b):
```

to

```
def add():
```

Later, when you have the other functions implemented as well you can do something like

```
# Choose what to do
choice = raw_input("Write what you want do do: add, subtract, multiply or divide")
if choice == 'add':
    add()
elif choice == 'subtract'
    subtract()
elif choice == 'multiply'
    multiply()
elif choice == 'divide'
    divide()
else:
    print 'not a valid choice'
```

---

> i plan on using the same template when doing multiply and divide etc.

In that case you could do something like this

```
def dostuff(command):
    print "Write the numbers to %s" (command)
    a = int(raw_input("First number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Second number: "))
    if command == 'add':
        return a + b
    elif command == 'subtract':
        return a - b
    elif command == 'multiply':
        return a * b
    elif command == 'divide':
        return a / b
    else:
        return 'not a valid command'

# Choose what to do
command = raw_input("Write what you want do do: add, subtract, multiply or divide")
print dostuff(command)
```

Comment: How do i return a value that is printed next? What i've edited doesnt seem to work..

Comment: @user3740983 I think what you mean can be achieved simply but putting all that code for the `dostuff()` function and the `#choose what to do` section in a `while True:` loop